# Upgrade from Unity 2018.3 to 2019.3 - Vuforia Problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have to work on one of my last year's projects again, developed with Unity 2018 and Vuforia 8.
When I open the project with the latest Unity 2019, I'm running into problems with Vuforia - see screenshots. I tried to update Vuforia to the latest version 9, but still having these issues.

Does anyone have a solution of this please :(

[image]

Comment: I think when using the Vuforia package you wouldn't need the scripts from Astes/Vuforia anymore but I might be wrong ... did you try to remove them? (**Backup first!**)

Comment: Awesome - Deleting the Vuforia folder, running the update to version 9, and restart was solving the problem. Thanks ;)